# Plug from laptop AC adapter was broke

Tags: voltage, ac, wire

When I tried to plug my AC adapter was broke. Here you can see it:

[image]

It's only the wire so I can replace it without any problem from my AC adapter. But my question is: Can I use any wire (while it has the same connector) or I have to check the voltage too?

I have an old wire with the same connector, I tried with it and it works. But I don't know if I can use it or it can damage my AC adapter (sending different voltage for example, I don't know). Here you can see physical differences (the old wire connector looks like the same, but I found a little difference, the holes are a a little bigger than my actual wire): http://postimg.org/image/j1obisnzr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fine as long as it fits snugly into the AC adapter.  There can be no difference in voltage between the two cables.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. One thing: "There can be no difference in voltage between the two cables." Then: Have not the cables any  difference in voltage or you are talking to me that I need to check that the two cables have not any difference in voltage?

Comment: I am sure you will find that the cables have simple wires running from one end to the other, so that the voltage reaching your AC adapter is the same as the voltage coming out of the wall.  This being the case, there is no difference between one cable and the other, and you can safely use the new cable to replace the old one.

Comment: Thank you Mike Spivey :) , I understand. I am going to mark your answer as solution.